# Insert Timestamp if Row is not blank

Tags: excel, vba

Essentially, I want to insert a timestamp for each row in column A if any other cells in that row are NOT blank. I want this to executive under my `Sub PASTE()` all at once.

I have a sub running which executives pasting specifics values to from columns to B:K on each row. I'd like this to finish running and then have it insert the timestamp for when it finished it column A. This way I can keep track of my analysis results, paste them in a worksheet and then timestamp them.

```vb
Sub PASTE()
    erw = Sheet8.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

    If Len(Range("D50")) <> 0 Then
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 2) = Sheet2.Range("D50")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 3) = Sheet2.Range("D51")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 4) = Sheet2.Range("D52")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 5) = Sheet2.Range("D53")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 6) = Sheet2.Range("D54")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 7) = Sheet2.Range("D55")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 8) = Sheet2.Range("D56")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 9) = Sheet2.Range("D57")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 10) = Sheet2.Range("D58")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 11) = Sheet2.Range("D59")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 12) = Sheet2.Range("D60")
        Sheet8.Cells(erw, 13) = Sheet2.Range("D61")

        Sheet2.Range("D50") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D51") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D52") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D53") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D54") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D55") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D56") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D57") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D58") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D59") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D60") = ""
        Sheet2.Range("D61") = ""
    Else
        MsgBox "You must enter the values"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Sheet8.Cells(erw, 1) = Now`?

Comment: Also `Sheet2.Range("D50:D61").Value = ""` to keep the code tidier

Comment: Also `Sheet8.Range("B" & erw & ":M" & erw) = Application.Transpose(Sheet2.Range("D50:D61")` to keep it even tidier (and even consider `With.... End With` methods to reference sheets :). Also note, you are only checking one cell for input currently.

Comment: `erw` should probably be `= Sheet8.Range("A" & Sheet8.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. Note that `Range("D50")` is implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. If that's supposed to be referring to `Sheet2`, make it `Sheet2.Range("D50")`